# How to see hidden or escape characters inside a varchar column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL 5.6.

I have a varchar column that stores addresses as text.

When they come through to my application into a text area box, they are spaced appropriately, like

```
123 Fake St.
Some City, NJ 12345
```

I tried inserting a new address directly into the database but it doesn't work correctly inside the GUI, it all came in as one line with no line break, like `123 Fake Str. Some City, NJ 12345`

I just want to be able to examine one of the addresses that does work to see how it was done (this was all done before my time at this company) so I can replicate it for the new address, as I have tried `\n`, `\r\n` to no success.

However, when I do `SELECT address FROM myTable` I just see it as plain text, no escaped characters.  How can I view the "raw" form of the address so that I can see how the line breaks were implemented?

Comment: What is in the text area box. Look at the HTML (I assume we are talking about html)

Comment: Text box is populated directly from the column in the string.  It's not a web application its a java swing one.  The same text box displays most of the addresses correctly, its the new ones I am trying to add to our database that are being displayed as a single line.

Comment: What tool do you use to poke about in the database? phpMyAdmin or something else

Comment: I use MySQL Work bench directly on it.

Comment: SO then its easy. Select a few of the old columns and then in the output area, click on a column cell and right click and use the menu item `Open Value In Editor` then look at the HEX using the hex tab

Comment: I think I've encountered this before. What I did was I had to do some workaround like changing all line breaks to <br> then return it back to \n when retrieving. I'm not sure if that's okay with you but you can do it as a last resort.

Comment: you can use the function **SELECT HEX(YOURFIELD) from yourTable** sample SELECT hex("hallo"); result : 68616C6C6F

Comment: Thank you all.  The hex indicates it is simply a \n, nothing special,  and a hex interpreter shows that I should be seeing the line break with my \n method, so it's an issue with how the  GUI is interpreting the data for some reason, not how I am storing the addresses.  If someone puts an answer I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try copying the value with the letter before and after into the hex function to see which character is being used. In this example in DBfiddle we see that the newline is `0A` which is char(11).
Without having your character we can't examine it!

> ```
> SELECT HEX('
> ') newline
> ```
>
> ```
> | newline |
> | :------ |
> | 0A      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fd00fbdc3fb2624668bf79f018e4e110)*

Comment: Yup, `HEX()` was the way to go.  Thank you.